# Error when adding group by calculated fields as new columns in pandas

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to add group by calculated fields (**mean, median, first and third quartile**) as new columns by using `transform` but received error message. I've also tried `map` but didn't work.

data
`d = {'col1':['a','b','c','c'], 'col2':['uk', 'tw', 'usa', 'tw'], 'col3':[1,3,3,4], 'col4':[1,1,1,1]}`

My code
`d['mean'] = d.groupby('col1')['col3'].transform('mean').reset_index(name='mean')`

Error `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1`

Also, how to calculate `quartile` with `transform` ?

Thanks

Comment: Do not `reset_index()`. That transform the series into a dataframe, which is not what you want.

Comment: thank you. It works fine. I received a warning in the real data `SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead`. It seems I need to change it to .loc. https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/  Do you know how to change it?

Comment: That means your `d` might be a copy of some bigger dataframe. Anywhere in your code that you have, for example, `d = some_df[some_condition]`?

Comment: Can you try `d.col3.groupby(d.col1).transform(lambda x: x.drop_duplicates().quantile())`
The data you created that might be a copy created of the original. If you want to check then you can try `d = d.copy(deep=True)` The error might go.

Comment: thank you @Steve_Greenwood   yes, I used lambda for quartile